# Why Are Excel Array Constants Base 1?

Tags: vba, excel

If you take this code and run it you would see that the initialization of the Array starts with 1 and not with 0.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim x() As Variant
    x = [{"A", "B"}]
    PrintArray x

    'this gives an error:
    'Debug.Print x.Count
'-----------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim k As Variant
    k = Array("C", "D")
    PrintArray k

End Sub

Public Sub PrintArray(ByRef myArray As Variant)

    Dim lngCounter As Long

    For lngCounter = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        Debug.Print lngCounter; " -> "; myArray(lngCounter)
    Next lngCounter
    Debug.Print TypeName(myArray)

End Sub
```

Any idea why?
This is the immediate window:

```
 1  -> A
 2  -> B
Variant()
 0  -> C
 1  -> D
Variant()
```

It somehow looks like `Collection`, but when I do `debug.print x.count` it gives an error.

If it was a `range`, then it should be giving a range in the TypeName like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Dim p As Variant
    Set p = Range("A1")
    Debug.Print TypeName(p)    
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe that the []'s are evaluating it, so it is looking like a range of 2 cells if you look at a()=range("a1:a2").value, they will start off index 1

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - good idea, but it prints `Variant` and not `Range` in the `TypeName`. See the edit of the question.

Comment: Not definitive, but I'd guess it has to do with `Application.Evaluate` which is implied by the square brackets, and how the `{}` notation is [typically representative of worksheet array constants](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

Comment: That's what I said "so it looks like a range of 2 cells"

Comment: But it's *not* a range of cells, nor a range of anything :) I'm certain that VBA doesn't treat it this way because it *looks like* a Range Array. Nathan I think you're probably on the right track, but the example you offered is too strict/specific and not applicable to the general case.

Comment: Array Constant expressions appear to be base-1, you can confirm in worksheet with: `=MATCH("D",{"A","B","C","D","E"},TRUE)`, which should return `4`.

Comment: Use x = Array("A", "B")

Comment: Excel arrays, ranges, collections start from 1. Starting from 0 is more of a programming thing

Comment: @Absinthe that doesn't even begin to answer the question.

Comment: @DavidZemens no, but it solves the implied problem

Comment: @Absinthe there's no problem implied, it's a question probing *why* they are different. Since OP clearly (by way of his own examples) is familiar with both methods of array instantiation, it seems not a very useful suggestion in any case.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Array Constants appear to be like Schroedinger's Cat, simultaneously base-1 and base-0. `=INDEX({1,2;3,4},0,2)` yields same result as `=INDEX({1,2;3,4},1,2)`, so whether you enter `0` or `1` for the row number, it returns the correct *first* row. Weird.

Comment: @DavidZemens - this thing with the `Index` is kind of creepy, yeah.

Comment: Yeah, definitely weird!!

Comment: @David no it doesn't. Try in VBA [] or Google sheet

Comment: @Slai I thought it was pretty obvious my last comment regarding to Worksheet formula :)

Comment: @Slai from VBA: `v = [INDEX({1,2;3,4},0,2)]` returns a 2-d slice of the array, values 2 & 4 whereas `v = [INDEX({1,2;3,4},1,2)]` returns only the value 2.

Comment: If you supply 0 as the row/column argument to Index, you get the entire row/column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize the array with values, it will always use standard VBA Lbound of 1.
When you initialize the array using Array(), it will use whatever you specify in Option Base (default 0).
If you put `Option Base 1` at the start of your module, and run your test you will see it running consistently.
[MSDN on Array()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264844(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: It seems to make sense. Thumbs up!

Comment: The "standard VBA Lbound" is 0, not 1, which is why `VBA.Array` uses 0 regardless of the `Option Base` statement.

Comment: With one exception - if you initialize like this `Dim x(5) As Long` it starts with a `0`.